# My Kotlin app is crashing due to a problem in profileFragment with Picasso

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My app keeps crashing. I have a problem in profileFragment with Picasso. I am using Kotlin.

This is error from Goggle Play Console

```
Crash Samsung Galaxy S7 Android 8.0 (SDK 26) 28.aab

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into (RequestCreator.java:682)
  at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into (RequestCreator.java:665)
  at com.MEDIA.media_jokes_wdz.Fragments.ProfileFragment$userInfo$1.onDataChange (ProfileFragment.kt:327)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent (ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire (DataEvent.java:63)
  at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run (EventRaiser.java:55)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:789)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6944)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Error coming from this code  // ProfileFragment:

```
private fun userInfo()
    {
        val usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(profileId)

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    val user = snapshot.getValue<User>(User::class.java)

                    Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(view?.pro_image_profile_frag)
                    view?.profile_fragment_username?.text = user!!.getUsername()
                    view?.full_name_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getFullname()
                    view?.bio_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getBio()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
```

This is line for error line 327

```
                Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(view?.pro_image_profile_frag)
```

Full Code ProfileFragment:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.MEDIA.media_jokes_wdz.AccountSettingsActivity
import com.MEDIA.media_jokes_wdz.Adapter.MyImagesAdapter
import com.MEDIA.media_jokes_wdz.Model.Post
import com.MEDIA.media_jokes_wdz.Model.User
import com.MEDIA.media_jokes_wdz.R
import com.MEDIA.media_jokes_wdz.ShowUsersActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_profile.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_profile.view.*
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [ProfileFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var profileId: String
    private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser

    var postList: List<Post>? = null
    var myImagesAdapter: MyImagesAdapter? = null

    var myImagesAdapterSavedImg: MyImagesAdapter? = null
    var postListSaved: List<Post>? = null
    var mySavesImg: List<String>? = null



    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
        val pref = context?.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        if (pref != null)
        {
            this.profileId = pref.getString("profileId", "none").toString()
        }

        if (profileId == firebaseUser.uid)
        {
            view.edit_account_settings_btn.text = "Edit Profile"
        }
        else if (profileId != firebaseUser.uid)
        {
            checkFollowAndFollowingButtonStatus()
        }



        //recycler view for Uploaded Images
        var recyclerViewUploadImages: RecyclerView
        recyclerViewUploadImages = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_upload_pic)
        recyclerViewUploadImages.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val  linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
        recyclerViewUploadImages.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager

        postList = ArrayList()
        myImagesAdapter = context?.let { MyImagesAdapter(it, postList as ArrayList<Post>) }
        recyclerViewUploadImages.adapter = myImagesAdapter


        //recycler view for Saved Images

        var recyclerViewSavedImages: RecyclerView
        recyclerViewSavedImages = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_saved_pic)
        recyclerViewSavedImages.setHasFixedSize(true)
        val  linearLayoutManager2: LinearLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
        recyclerViewSavedImages.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager2

        postListSaved = ArrayList()
        myImagesAdapterSavedImg = context?.let { MyImagesAdapter(it, postListSaved as ArrayList<Post>) }
        recyclerViewSavedImages.adapter = myImagesAdapterSavedImg


        recyclerViewSavedImages.visibility = View.GONE
        recyclerViewUploadImages.visibility = View.VISIBLE



        var uploadedImagesBtn: ImageButton
        uploadedImagesBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.images_grid_view_btn)
        uploadedImagesBtn.setOnClickListener {
            recyclerViewSavedImages.visibility = View.GONE
            recyclerViewUploadImages.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        var savedImagesBtn: ImageButton
        savedImagesBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.images_save_btn)
        savedImagesBtn.setOnClickListener {
            recyclerViewSavedImages.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            recyclerViewUploadImages.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        view.total_followers.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, ShowUsersActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("id", profileId)
            intent.putExtra("title", "followers")
            startActivity(intent)
        }

        view.total_following.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(context, ShowUsersActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("id", profileId)
            intent.putExtra("title", "following")
            startActivity(intent)
        }





        view.edit_account_settings_btn.setOnClickListener {
            val getButtonText = view.edit_account_settings_btn.text.toString()

            when
            {
                getButtonText == "Edit Profile" -> startActivity(Intent(context, AccountSettingsActivity::class.java))

                getButtonText == "Follow" -> {

                    firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                            .child("Following").child(profileId)
                            .setValue(true)
                    }

                    firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child("Follow").child(profileId)
                            .child("Followers").child(it1.toString())
                            .setValue(true)
                    }

                    addNotification()

                }

                getButtonText == "Following" -> {

                    firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                            .child("Following").child(profileId)
                            .removeValue()
                    }

                    firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
                        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                            .child("Follow").child(profileId)
                            .child("Followers").child(it1.toString())
                            .removeValue()
                    }

                }
            }


        }


        getFollowers()
        getFollowing()
        userInfo()
        myPhotos()
        getTotalNumberOfPosts()
        mySaves()


        return view
    }

    private fun checkFollowAndFollowingButtonStatus()
    {
        val followingRef = firebaseUser?.uid.let { it1 ->
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Follow").child(it1.toString())
                .child("Following")
        }
        if (followingRef != null)
        {
            followingRef.addValueEventListener(object  : ValueEventListener{
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
                {
                    if (snapshot.child(profileId).exists())
                    {
                        view?.edit_account_settings_btn?.text = "Following"
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        view?.edit_account_settings_btn?.text = "Follow"
                    }
                }

                override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError) {

                }
            })
        }
    }

    private fun getFollowers()
    {
        val followersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Follow").child(profileId)
                .child("Followers")



        followersRef.addValueEventListener(object  : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    view?.total_followers?.text = snapshot.childrenCount.toString()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })
    }




    private fun getFollowing()
    {
        val followersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                .child("Follow").child(profileId)
                .child("Following")


        followersRef.addValueEventListener(object  : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    view?.total_following?.text = snapshot.childrenCount.toString()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })
    }

    private fun myPhotos()
    {
        val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
        postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    (postList as ArrayList<Post>).clear()

                    for (snapshot in snapshot.children)
                    {
                        val post = snapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)!!
                        if (post.getPublisher().equals(profileId))
                        {
                            (postList as ArrayList<Post>).add(post)
                        }
                        Collections.reverse(postList)
                        myImagesAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    }
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })
    }
    private fun userInfo()
    {
        val usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(profileId)

        usersRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (snapshot.exists())
                {
                    val user = snapshot.getValue<User>(User::class.java)

                    Picasso.get().load(user!!.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(view?.pro_image_profile_frag)
                    view?.profile_fragment_username?.text = user!!.getUsername()
                    view?.full_name_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getFullname()
                    view?.bio_profile_frag?.text = user!!.getBio()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()

        val pref = context?.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?.edit()
        pref?.putString("profileId", firebaseUser.uid)
        pref?.apply()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()

        val pref = context?.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?.edit()
        pref?.putString("profileId", firebaseUser.uid)
        pref?.apply()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        val pref = context?.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)?.edit()
        pref?.putString("profileId", firebaseUser.uid)
        pref?.apply()
    }

    private fun getTotalNumberOfPosts()
    {
        val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")

        postsRef.addValueEventListener(object  : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    var postCounter = 0
                    for (snapShot in dataSnapshot.children)
                    {
                        val post = snapShot.getValue(Post::class.java)!!
                        if (post.getPublisher() == profileId)
                        {
                            postCounter++
                        }
                    }
                    total_posts.text = " " + postCounter
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }

    private fun mySaves()
    {
        mySavesImg = ArrayList()

        val savedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .reference
            .child("Saves").child(firebaseUser.uid)

        savedRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children)
                    {
                        (mySavesImg as ArrayList<String>).add(snapshot.key!!)
                    }
                    readSavedImagesData()
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })

    }

    private fun readSavedImagesData()
    {
        val postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")

        postsRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener
        {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                    (postListSaved as ArrayList<Post>).clear()
                    for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children)
                    {
                        val post = snapshot.getValue(Post::class.java)

                        for (key in mySavesImg!!)
                        {
                            if (post!!.getPostid() == key)
                            {
                                (postListSaved as ArrayList<Post>).add(post!!)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    myImagesAdapterSavedImg!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(snapshot: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }




    private fun addNotification()
    {
        val notiRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .reference.child("Notifications")
            .child(profileId)

        val notiMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
        notiMap["userid"] = firebaseUser!!.uid
        notiMap["text"] = "started following you"
        notiMap["postid"] = ""
        notiMap["ispost"] = false

        notiRef.push().setValue(notiMap)
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey there, please take note that the [tag:javascript] tag should not be used for questions unrelated to [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) - instead, use the [tag:java] tag (and **only if your code is in Java**).

Comment: Just because I commented on this question doesn't mean that I downvoted.

Comment: ok nvm but when i told u about  -1 , someone marked it off immediately